# How to include file from multiple directory

Tags: php, oop

I am working in PHP. I tried hard to find a solution. Maybe some expert definitely gives me a proper solution.

'core/init.php' load / call all classes and functions. In bottom, other pages like 'index.php' , 'login.php' include the core/init.php. I already do that one. No problem is when admin login and in 'dashboard.php' he can see 'due_payment.php'. But i cannot include the 'core/init.php' file because it check in the '/admin' section.

I know it's something messy. Hope someone gives me a better Idea.

[image: This is the directories I am using]

[image]

Comment: `include '../core/init.php';` ?

Comment: No.this is not the solution. As I said in core/init.php file  I also load classes like DB.php, Config.php. I need the base url so that i can include core file from any directory

Comment: This could help you [spl-autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) and [Autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) you can find many examples about it

Comment: you have to have one *fixpoint* that you include and that will set some constants or functions. for example in your core/init.php `function basepath() { return dirname(__DIR__).'/'; }` and for all other includes: `include basePath().'/includes/db.php` or whatever. except for the core (included with relative paths) every other include should be done with the basepath (which effectively turns everything into absolute paths).